# What is the meaning of "equivalent webpages" in Freebase?

Tags: html, freebase

I started to work on Freebase. I have some confusion concerning webpages:

In the following [link](https://github.com/paulhoule/RDFeasy/wiki/Complete-Edition) they describe *equivalent webpages* as links to outside web pages. These outside pages are Wikipedia pages and Freebase pages, IMDb pages etc.

**What do they mean by "outside pages"?** I didn't understand, outside to what exactly? Is it outside to the entity?

The outside pages for [Barack Obama](https://www.freebase.com/m/02mjmr) are:

> - http://www.nytimes.com/top/reference/timestopics/people/o/barack_obama
> - http://www.nndb.com/people/208/000055043/
> - http://bioguide.congress.gov/scripts/biodisplay.pl?index=O000167
> - http://openlibrary.org/authors/OL529531A
> - http://www.myspace.com/barackobama
> - http://www.tvrage.com/person/id-82898
> - http://id.loc.gov/authorities/names/n94112934.html
> - http://viaf.org/viaf/52010985/
> - http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/index.html?curid=297666
> - http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/index.html?curid=167398

Are these pages unique for "Barack Obama"? We can't consider them as unique identifiers.

Are these the pages where the entity "Barack Obama" appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may be vague as I don't have a copy of freebase. Based on the link you provided though they appear to be links/uris used as values somehow for the [Topic Equivalent Webpage](https://www.freebase.com/common/topic/topic_equivalent_webpage?schema=) property. `topic_equivalent_webpage` has a description:

> Webpages which are singular in focus describing a Topic. (i.e., a page which is only about the Topic.)

So this is what they are - they have a single focus, describe the topic (Barack Obama in this case), and could come from anywhere on the Web. I am not sure of false-positives in freebase, so I would be cautious to consider them as unique identifiers for the topic. I feel these are more like `rdfs:seeAlso` values in Semantic Web terms, rather than equivalent/sameAs entities. You can run a few checks in your KB:

1. You can check if there are any `owl:sameAs` links between these pages and the Barack Obama entity. In that case, you may consider them as equivalent in the absolute sense (e.g. whatever is asserted about Barack Obama can propagate and hold for the "equivalent" entity/page). Again, in the context of your KB/freebase.
2. Assuming these are values for the `topic_equivalent_webpage` property, you can check if the property has a `rdfs:subPropertyOf` or `owl:equivalentProperty` relation with `owl:sameAs`. In that case, your knowledge base considers them as equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of them can be considered strong identifiers.  You can tell which ones by looking at the Keys tab https://www.freebase.com/m/02mjmr?keys=

This is one of Freebase's greatest strengths, this abundance of reconciled entity identifiers to an wide variety of different external information sources (Wikipedia, IMDB, MusicBrainz, Library of Congress, etc, etc).

Each key is associated with a namespace in which it is unique and each namespace has an associated URI Template which is used to construct the URIs from the keys.  For example, the Congressional Bioguide URL is associated with a namespace controlled by the Library of Congress and populated with the THOMAS IDs which are used to identify legislators.

It is (or was) possible for Freebase users to add other fully formed URLs, but it rarely happened.  If you work from the keys though, you can be guaranteed to only get strong identifiers, not random URLs.

EDIT: Here's what they look like in the bulk Freebase RDF dump:

```
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.010q36>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/common.topic.topic_equivalent_webpage>  <http://openlibrary.org/authors/OL514554A>  .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.010q36>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/book.author.openlibrary_id> "OL514554A" .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.010q36>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.key>    "/authority/openlibrary/author/OL514554A"   .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.010q36>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/key/authority.openlibrary.author>  "OL514554A" .
```

Abbreviated for better presentation:

```
<s> <fb:/ns/common.topic.topic_equivalent_webpage>  <http://openlibrary.org/authors/OL514554A>  .
<s> <fb:/ns/book.author.openlibrary_id> "OL514554A" .
<s> <fb:/ns/type.object.key>    "/authority/openlibrary/author/OL514554A"   .
<s> <fb:/key/authority.openlibrary.author>  "OL514554A" .
```

The single OpenLibrary identifier is presented in four different forms, which is a bit excessive, the important piece is that anything in the `/authority` name space can be relied upon as a strong identifier.